# dygraphs error with Paris time zone

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I got this in the console :

```
Unable to parse ' Madrid)' as a number on line 2 ('Thu Jan 01 1970 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Paris, Madrid),100') of CSV.
```

When I change my computer time zone, for example Berlin, Dygraphs works properly.
new Date() gives this for Berlin :

```
Fri Mar 25 2016 09:05:31 GMT+0100 (Central Europe Standard Time)
```

And for Paris :

```
Fri Mar 25 2016 09:04:57 GMT+0100 (Paris, Madrid)
```

It seems Dygraphs doesn't like commas in the time zone. How can I solve this problem, please?

Comment: Could you post the code that produces this error ?

Comment: If you're loading a CSV file, then the problem might be the comma in your time zone name.